# MongoDB: User defined variable into query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm new to MongoDB shell and I need some help !

I have 2 collections: **movies** and **comments**. I want to store a value from the second collection and use it to find something in the first.

This is what I have tried :

```
var result = db.comments.findOne({name: "Arya Stark"})
var movieId = JSON.stringify(result.movie_id.valueOf())
db.movies.findOne({_id: ObjectId($$movieId)})
```

The above prints that `$$movieId` is not defined. I have also tried :

```
db.movies.find({_id: {$toObjectId: movieId}})
```

and even though my version is 4.2.3, it prints:

> unknown operator: $toObjectId.

I have tried everything, I don't know what else to do.

**EDIT :**

**Here's the printed result :**

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a9427648b0beebeb6957d48"),
        "name" : "Arya Stark",
        "email" : "maisie_williams@gameofthron.es",
        "movie_id" : ObjectId("573a1392f29313caabcd9906"),
        "text" : "Laborum incidunt asperiores accusamus facilis vitae ut quidem. Praesentium provident explicabo odit dolores unde amet architecto. Iure id vero temporibus assumenda eum quia.",
        "date" : ISODate("1978-07-29T23:20:45Z")
}
```

Basically I want to take the movie_id from the collection **comments** and use it in the collection **movies** to search from which movie it is.

Comment: Well... I afraid we should have before hand a sample of both collections

Comment: Edited! Hope it's helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do two database calls, instead use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) for **JOINS**, try to execute below query in shell :

```
db.comments.aggregate([{ $match: { name: "Arya Stark" } }, {
    $lookup:
    {
        from: "movies",
        localField: "movie_id",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "movie"
    }
}, { $unwind: '$movie' }])
```

Your two issues are :

1. when you use `$$` in your query that respective variable has to be declared locally in query itself.
2. [$toObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toObjectId/index.html) is an aggregation operator, which can't be used like that in `.find()`.

Comment: Thank you for your response! However this is not what I'm trying to do. To be more specific I want to find one random comment from user "Arya Stark", store the movie_id and then use it to find the specific movie from the "movies" collection. The thing is that the _id field accepts values of ObjectId type and I only have the id in string. For example what I have is: "573a1392f29313caabcd9906" but I want it to look like this ObjectId("573a1392f29313caabcd9906"). I can't find a way to pass my variable into the query..

Comment: @MaryVoulieri : So you mean to say you need random doc from `comments` collection with specific user ? So for that case add this stage`{ $sample: { size: 1 } }` in between `$match` & `$lookup`. which would get random document for filter `{ name: "Arya Stark" }` & using this query you can do things in one DB call & should work, let me know if doesn't work for you - will update answer..

Comment: Thank you very much that's exactly what I wanted to do!

Comment: What can be used instead of `$toObjectId` in case of find()?

Comment: @SamuraiJack : what are you trying to do ? Db version ?

Comment: 4.2 but could use latest. See if you could help me with this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63633710/how-serialize-mongodb-objectiduniqueid-to-json-in-nodejs

pls read the comments on one of the posts.