# How serialize MongoDb ObjectId("uniqueid") to JSON in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb, mongodb-query

Let's assume we have a query builder service B that spits out mongo db query when called. This query is received by service A and it executes it as is with mongo db official nodejs driver.

How do I send something like :

```
[{
  _id: new mongo.ObjectID("5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2d96"),
  phone: "666"
}, {
  _id: new mongo.ObjectID("5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2da2"),
  phone: "555"
}]
```

from service B to service A?

EDIT:

The following works perfectly fine:

```
var q = { _id: new mongo.ObjectID("5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2d96") };
const result = await this.db.collection("persons").find(q).toArray();
```

The following doesn't work:

```
var q = { _id: { $oid: "5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2d96" } }
const result = await this.db.collection("persons").find(q).toArray();
```

Now,

```
var q = { _id: new mongo.ObjectID("5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2d96") };
JSON.stringify(q)
```

gives you : `{"_id":"5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2d96"}` and if you pass this to service A. You can not use it in service A as follows:

```
  const result = await this.db.collection("persons").find(qStr).toArray();
```

Or as,

```
  const result = await this.db.collection("persons").find(JSON.parse(qStr)).toArray();
```

Comment: what is the issue when `var q = { _id: new mongo.ObjectID("5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2d96") };
const result = await this.db.collection("persons").find(q).toArray();` is used?

Comment: No issue at all. It works perfectly fine in service B. But the question is how do you send this to service A and execute it in service A? @whoami

Comment: Yes I mean what's happening when you send it to `service A` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

- Serialize your documents to extended json on one end
- Deserialize your documents from extended json to language-native data structures on the other end

See https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson#node-no-bundling for how to serialize and deserialize.

You cannot feed extended json-type annotated hashes to driver functions that expect native types (which are all of them, basically, other than the one that specifically parses extended json), like you tried to do.

```
var q = { _id: new mongo.ObjectID("5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2d96") };
const serializedQ = BSON.serialize(q);
const deserializedQ = BSON.deserialize(serializedQ);    
const result = await this.db.collection("persons").find(deserializedQ).toArray();
```

Comment: yep, that's exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: However I do have a question. `BSON.serialize(q)` does not give you a string. So is it possible to send it to another service in HTTP call?

Comment: BSON is a binary format, you should be getting a binary string after serializing to it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a standard that MongoDB calls "[Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/)" that defines how you can encode all BSON data types in regular JSON.

It will become something like

```
{ _id : {$oid: "5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2d96"} }
```

Most MongoDB tools will be able to convert to and from that format.

Comment: I thought so too. But the following query fails to execute:
 
`const result = await this.db.collection("persons").bulkWrite([{ _id: {"$oid":"5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2d96"} , phone: "666" }
        , { _id: {"$oid":"5d505646cf6d4fe581014ab2"}  , phone: "555" }].map(function (p) {
          return {
            updateOne: {
              filter: { _id: p._id },
              update: { $set: { phone: p.phone } }
            }
          }
        }))`

Comment: and if you mean that `{ _id : {$oid: "5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2d96"} }`
 is to be converted to  `new mongo.ObjectID("5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2d96")`, is there a programmatic way of doing that?  like `BSON.parse({$oid: "5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2d96"})`

Comment: How do I convert `[{"_id":"5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2d96","phone":"666"},{"_id":"5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2da2","phone":"555"}];` into 
`{ _id: new mongo.ObjectID("5f3258cfbaaccedaa5dd2d96"), phone: "232" }` and vice verse ?

Comment: @SamuraiJack: no issue with this answer! So let's say data is transferred between two systems in the form of `JSON` specific `JSON string` as `ObjectId()` is not of JSON type, this query can be converted to JSON string transferred to other service where it can be `JSON.parse()` and executed on DB as is where I believe DB will convert `string` to `ObjectId()` but if you wanted this conversion to happen in code then `service B` will do `new mongo.ObjectID("")` but in transfer `ObjectId()` will be converted to `string`, again in `service A` needs to convert string to objectId

Comment: @whoami please see my edit. I have tried to explain myself.